# Elixir application runs a PHP script

Tags: php, elixir, stdin

I'm writing an elixir application that needs to communicate with several APIs.

One api is a connection to Post Affiliate Pro which uses PHP and has a PHP class file you can download to use their API easily.

As I seach for answer online my results are overwhelmed about using PHP to run elixir which is the opposite of wha. I need

I know nothing about PHP, I don't even know what dependencies I'll need on the server to run a php script.

My elixir program currently runs an executable using `System.cmd()`.

Would it be possible to use `System.cmd()` to run the script file and have the output of the PHP script be routed to elixir's STDIN? I've never done that before but maybe I should start there? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a script designed to be run from the command line, the you should be able to run it with `System.cmd/1`. First try to run the script manually from the command line and get it working.

I would start with ensuring that you have php installed on your system. If not, you will need to install it.

The other option is to use the php script to understand the API its using and create your own in Elixir, using a http client.

Comment: I'd like to connect and use the API directly with Elixir, but they don't seem to have good documentation for the regular Rest API stuff. All their documentation focuses on how to use their custom PHP api class. Its unfortunate.

Comment: have you looked at the php script? php is pretty easy to read. If you want, throw it up on a gist and I can take a quick look to evaluate it

Comment: I've never done anything in PHP, so no I haven't looked at it, but I will, here it is: https://gist.github.com/LegitStack/b4543707760d00cfe94959c548dc672b To get the information I need I've been told:

You can use Pap_Api_AffiliatesGrid --> https://support.qualityunit.com/608550-Pap_Api_AffiliatesGrid which you can use it to search and filter in affiliates.

Then, you can use High-Level API Pap_Api_Affiliate, https://support.qualityunit.com/961744-Pap_Api_Affiliate where you can pull out Parent User Identity via "getParentUserId()" method.

Comment: have you seen http://docs.affiliatewp.com/category/1776-rest-api-extended Do you think you could use that API. If you can, it would be the simplest. The examples you were given look like they assume you are calling the api from an PHP site since they are initializing the api with a session object.

Comment: I don't think that API connects to the right URL. We are working with postaffiliatepro.Com